# injecting value in default layout in handlebars

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

i am trying to display username in my main template if user is logged in or some other text if not

here is the part of my main template where i would like to display username

```
<a class="nav-link nav-link-white dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">

                        {{username}}

                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-down ml-2"></i>
                    </a>
```

here is the part of my main file that is server.js where i created the helper

```
        var handlebars = exphbs.create({
        extname: '.hbs',
        defaultLayout: "main",
        layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, "app/views"),
        helpers: {

            }
        }
    });
```

this the is middleware that checks if user is logged in

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    res.redirect('/');
}
```

here is the user module

```
    module.exports = function (sequelize, Sequelize) {

        var User = sequelize.define('user', {
            id: { autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true, type: Sequelize.INTEGER },
            firstname: { type: Sequelize.STRING, notEmpty: true },
            lastname: { type: Sequelize.STRING, notEmpty: true },
            mobileno: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
            email: { type: Sequelize.STRING, validate: { isEmail: true } },
            password: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
            last_login: { type: Sequelize.DATE }
             }

        });

        return User;

}
```

now how will i check if user is logged in and if user is logged in then display the username else display some other text.
i tried displaying other text in the main file and its working but how to get the firstname of the user if user is logged in.

Comment: `app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.login = req.isAuthenticated();
    next();
});` adding this to the code and checking in client-side works but how to do this on server-side.

Comment: `helpers: {       
        log: function (res) {
            if (res.isAuthenticated){                
                return "LoggedIn"
            } else {
                return "notLoggedin"
            }
        }
    }`
 i tried using this but it always displays notLoggedIn